# Including subschemas in schemas doesn't seem to work for mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

This is how I defined my subschema and schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const JobSchema = new Schema ({
    jobname: String,
    jobstatus: String
})

const DataSchema = new Schema ({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    jobs: [JobSchema]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("data", DataSchema);
```

This block of code is to utilize the schema above as a model

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const Data = require("../../models/Data");

router.post("/", (req, res) => {
    const newData = new Data({
        username: req.body.username,
        jobs: req.body.jobs
    });
    newData
        .save()
        .then(data => res.json(data))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
});

module.exports = router;
```

Data I attempted to put in:

```
{
    username: France,
    jobs: [{jobname: Google, jobstatus: applied}]
}
```

Error:

```
Error: data validation failed: jobs: Cast to embedded failed for value "'[{jobname: Google, jobstatus: applied}]'" at path "jobs"
    at ValidationError.inspect (/Users/Desktop/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:48:26)
    at formatValue (internal/util/inspect.js:723:31)
    at inspect (internal/util/inspect.js:289:10)
    at formatWithOptionsInternal (internal/util/inspect.js:1918:40)
    at formatWithOptions (internal/util/inspect.js:1802:10)
    at Object.Console.<computed> (internal/console/constructor.js:304:10)
    at Object.log (internal/console/constructor.js:314:61)
    at /Users/Desktop/server/routes/api/data.js:14:31
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  errors: {
    jobs: CastError: Cast to embedded failed for value "'[{jobname: Google, jobstatus: applied}]'" at path "jobs"
        at DocumentArrayPath.cast (/Users/Desktop/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/documentarray.js:449:19)
        at DocumentArrayPath.cast (/Users/Desktop/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/documentarray.js:378:17)
        at DocumentArrayPath.SchemaType.applySetters (/Users/Desktop/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1031:12)
        at model.$set (/Users/Desktop/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1203:20)
        at model._handleIndex (/Users/Desktop/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:979:14)
        at model.$set (/Users/Desktop/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:920:22)
        at model.Document (/Users/Desktop/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:137:12)
        at model.Model (/Users/Desktop/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:106:12)
        at new model (/Users/Desktop/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4695:15)
        at /Users/Desktop/server/routes/api/data.js:7:21
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/Desktop/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
        at next (/Users/Desktop/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
        at Route.dispatch (/Users/Desktop/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/Desktop/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
        at /Users/Desktop/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
        at Function.process_params (/Users/Desktop/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12) {
      stringValue: `"'[{jobname: Google, jobstatus: applied}]'"`,
      messageFormat: undefined,
      kind: 'embedded',
      value: "'[{jobname: Google, jobstatus: applied}]'",
      path: 'jobs',
      reason: ObjectParameterError: Parameter "obj" to Document() must be an object, got [{jobname: Google, jobstatus: applied}]
          at EmbeddedDocument.Document (/Users/Desktop/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:90:11)
          at EmbeddedDocument [as constructor] (/Users/Desktop/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/embedded.js:42:12)
          at new EmbeddedDocument (/Users/Desktop/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/documentarray.js:115:17)
          at DocumentArrayPath.cast (/Users/Desktop/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/documentarray.js:442:22)
          at DocumentArrayPath.cast (/Users/Desktop/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/documentarray.js:378:17)
          at DocumentArrayPath.SchemaType.applySetters (/Users/Desktop/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1031:12)
          at model.$set (/Users/Desktop/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1203:20)
          at model._handleIndex (/Users/Desktop/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:979:14)
          at model.$set (/Users/Desktop/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:920:22)
          at model.Document (/Users/Desktop/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:137:12)
          at model.Model (/Users/Desktop/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:106:12)
          at new model (/Users/Desktop/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4695:15)
          at /Users/Desktop/server/routes/api/data.js:7:21
          at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/Desktop/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
          at next (/Users/Desktop/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
          at Route.dispatch (/Users/Desktop/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    }
  },
  _message: 'data validation failed'
}
```

I have read from several sources on the internet that the idea of subschemas(a.k.a subdocuments) is possible. However, when I try to implement it as shown above, it fails to work. What is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error looks like you are assigning a string to `jobs` instead of the array object. I think what you are currently saving is

```js
{
    username: "France",
    jobs: "[{jobname: Google, jobstatus: applied}]" // the whole array as string
}
```

What you should be saving is

```js
{
    username: "France",
    jobs: [{jobname: "Google", jobstatus: "applied"}]
}
```

Please console log the `req.body.jobs` and check if its a proper JSON array

Comment: Thanks, turns out I've been using postman wrongly, btw do you have any experience with postman before. I just wanna ask because for some reason my server doesn't seem to read in the contents of the jobs array and just records it as an empty array. Hope somebody can help!

Comment: Okay, so can you provide a sample request body that's send from postman

Answer (score 0):

You can't use schema in another schema by storing it in a "jobs".
You can give a reference to "jobschema" as below.

jobs : [{

type: Schema.ObjectId, 
ref: 'JobSchema'

}]

Comment: Error: data validation failed: jobs: Cast to [ObjectId] failed for value "["[{jobname: Google, jobstatus: applied}]"]" at path "jobs".

I'm still getting this error though.